# i dont want to show the first 3 records of a table then what is the query for that

Tags: sql

```
select * 
from tour 
where user_id start from 4;
```

Comment: Can you please check the answer for your query , if still any concern let me know ..

Comment: Tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no such thing as the "first 3 records".  Ordering is only determined by data, so you need a column to specify the ordering.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use `row_number()` to achieve this.

```
select * from (select *,row_number() over (order by user_id) rn from tour) t1
where rn > 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Use can use limit

```
SELECT * FROM tour where user_id >3 LIMIT 3 OFFSET 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code.

```
select *
from tour
where user_id not in (select top 3 user_id from tour order by user_id)
order by user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

In standard SQL you would use `fetch first` but this only makes sense if you also provide an ORDER BY clause to define the order of the rows, e.g.:

```
select *
from tour
order by user_id
fetch first 3 rows only;
```

If you want to start at a given row (based on the sort order defined by `ORDER BY`)  you can add the `offset` clause:

```
select *
from tour
order by user_id
offset 3
fetch next 5 rows only;
```

If you only want to skip the first rows, you can leave out the `fetch next`part:

```
select *
from tour
order by user_id
offset 3;
```

Both statements are standard ANSI SQL, but not all DBMS products support that (but you only tagged your question with [sql](/questions/tagged/sql) which refers to ANSI SQL)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this query for your problem , this query will show all records except the first 3 records.

```
SELECT *
FROM tour
WHERE user_id >= 4
ORDER BY user_id OFFSET 3 ROWS;
```